# What policies or rights to be provided for a user with which we will run the terraform scripts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

We are creating eks clusters and other resources from terraform.

What are the policies to be given to that user account?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is: it fully depends on your needs.

If you're running Terraform on CodeBuild or ECS and have configured an [IAM Task Role](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html), Terraform will use the container's Task Role.

If you're running Terraform on EKS and have configured [IAM Roles for Service Accounts (IRSA)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/iam-roles-for-service-accounts.html), Terraform will use the pod's role.

See [AWS Identity and Access Management Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iam/index.html) for always up to date information and test your policies with the help of [IAM policy simulator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_testing-policies.html).

However, from my experience it is much easier to use AWS managed policies than to write policies yourself - see [AWS managed policies for Amazon Elastic Kubernetes Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/security-iam-awsmanpol.html) for an overview.